# Cannot set properties of null, setting onmessage when receiving data through websocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

Getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onmessage')
```

For context; I am building a pair programming platform. I connect users to a websocket when they navigate to a particular page. I have a separate send function that is triggered every time the Driver of the pair programming session types in something. This code is sent to the passenger through the websocket. There is a separate method that listens and waits to hear from the server.

The error I am getting seems to be coming from this method:

```
class WebSocketService {
   ...
   constructor() {
    this.socketRef = null;
  }
  ...
    response(){
        this.socketRef= null;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.socketRef.onmessage = e => {
                var response = JSON.parse(e.data)
                console.log(`!!!! response: ${JSON.stringify(response)} !!!`)
                resolve(response)
            }
            
        })
    }
}
```

This method is triggered inside a useEffect:

```
useEffect((() => {
    WebSocketInstance.response().then((res) => {
        var temp = res ? JSON.parse(res.text) : ''
        received.current = temp ? temp.data : ''
    })
}))
```

I initially connect the user to a websocket. If the user is the driver of the pair programming session, I trigger a function that sends the code the driver types into the code editor to the passenger and then the passenger receives the code sent.

Comment: You yourself set `this.socketRef = null` two lines above! So of course it will be `null` then, and `null.onmessage = ...` is not a valid operation.

Answer (score 0):

You've set in the constructor:

`this.socketRef = null;`

so you're trying to access a **non** existing property.

if you want to start with a *null* value inside the onmessage you should do

```
this.socketRef.onmessage = null;
```